# "Looking for a job" panel placement delay causing click problems

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I have an issue with the "Looking for a job" panel that appears on SO pages.

At least in my browser (Chrome on Windows) and via my work's crappy internet connection, there is a slight delay before this panel appears and pushes other content down. This means that sometimes I inadvertently click on the "Looking for a job" panel when I meant to click on something else.

Here's an example of what I see when the page loads:

[image]

and what I see after a short delay:

[image]

See how the panel has pushed the "Frequented Tags" section down. So the page loads, I go to click on the "c#" tag, and just at that moment the jobs panel appears and I get taken to that page instead.

If there anything that can be done about this?

Comment: That might be the reason why the panel did so well in A/B testing :) The ad with the best click-trough rate was simply the one with the most optimized delay.

Comment: @Sri Technically the other was a duplicate of this as I posted mine first, but whatever

Comment: The other had more votes so I flagged it as a duplicate of it

Comment: @Sri Fair enough if that's how things work, although it does make me look like a bit of a muppet who didn't research the question enough before posting

Comment: Well duplicates happen and titles are completely different and your question didn't have any specific tag like the other had [meta-tag:careers] tag so SO search which is not efficient might not have showed your post in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't notice this post, but someone posted [the same issue a few days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285919/careers-block-position).

We've moved the favorite tags section above the ads on the `/questions` page as well now. Hopefully that solves the annoyance for most people.

Answer (score 5):

The "Frequented Tags" section should be shown above the ad.  When the ad loads it will push down the "Hot Network Questions" but the display placement of the Frequented Tags should remain in place.  Let me know if you have further issues.

Comment: What about just adding the ad's size to the css or html, so there's a paceholder first?

Comment: @Geoff Dalgas This is true for the home page, however if I click on, say, the "c#" tag link to go to questions related to C#, then on *that* page the jobs ads panel pushes down the "Related Tags" section. I often want to look at questions tagged both "c#" *and* "wpf", so I start at the home page, click the "c#" tag link, then click the "wpf" tag link under "Related Tags". This used to work fine. Since the recent changes I am now often clicking on the job ad by mistake.

Comment: @Geoff Dalgas As you've tagged this as "status-completed" does this mean the current behaviour is by-design? As I wrote in my earlier comment, certain pages of SO are still placing the job ads panel above the list of clickable tags (eg. "Related Tags" section on some pages).