# Careers block position

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

On [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) `Looking for a job?` block appears above `Favorite Tags`:

[image]

And it causes inconvenience for me, because it takes some time for careers block to appear. And before jobs block appears, I see tags on that place. Everyday I go on questions page, want to click on tag and boom! careers block appears and brings me to some job which was just loaded. I already missclicked for like 10 times during past few days.

For better understanding, check this gif:

[image]

By the way, on [stackoverflow main page](https://stackoverflow.com/) it appears contrariwise:

[image]

which keeps `Favorite Tags` on same place before and after careers block being loaded. Maybe it should be done in the same way on questions page?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251763/move-favourite-tags-above-the-community-bulletin-careers

Comment: @Mat thanks, but this is a bit different question. Jobs block started to appear recently and it really interfere. I mean this isn't about comfort like on link you mentioned. I can't browse questions by tags normally because of this.

Comment: This behaviour is indeed very annoying:(

Comment: Agreed. That is ___incredibly annoying___. We'll fix it either by reserving that space so it doesn't jump, or by moving it. I'll post an answer when that's in place.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: You could just hide those panels so your favorites appear higher up like I ended up doing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276130/57475

Comment: Strongly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285233/looking-for-a-job-panel-placement-delay-causing-click-problems

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been fixed. You'll notice that favorite tags are now above the ads on the [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) route. It took a day because one of our Q&A developers (Jarrod Dixon) decided to take this as an opportunity to clean up some old code in views relating to tag preferences.

Thank you for reporting this issue, and I sincerely apologize for the annoyance. We aim to have ads be as unobtrusive as possible, while still being effective. In this case, they were objectively hurting usability, so we're happy to fix it.