# Please decide on a place for the "Looking for a job" legend

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The Stack Overflow "Looking for a job?" menu on the right hand side of the screen is a relatively new addition to the website. It is modest enough that users can ignore it but also informative enough that I will often read the top job listings for interest.

The only issue I have is that currently it doesn't seem to have a fixed place in the website.

To elaborate, if you click on the questions tab then for two seconds the "related tags" menu appears before being over written by the jobs menu.

This can also happen with the "linked" and "related" menus on the right when clicking on a question.

This is frustrating for a number of reasons:

1. It is easy to try to click for a tag and get the job menu instead
2. More scrolling is required to get to the more used menus on the right
3. There is increased flicker on the screen due to the screen reloading and changing

I know that reading that list the reasons all seem small and insignificant but it is a shame such a useful tool has been added and is detracting from the user experience of the website.

If it were had a fixed location and always loaded in this place it would be far less irritating. Even if it were at the top of the list I could get used to that (although not ideal). Instead it loads itself under my mouse, like a body guard saving the president, which is frustrating.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285062/where-is-the-option-to-remove-looking-for-a-job and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285233/looking-for-a-job-panel-placement-delay-causing-click-problems.

Comment: I don't want to remove it. I just don't want it jumping around the screen

Comment: Hence "related" – they're both about issues with the placement of the panel.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this isn't technically _new_, it's actually been around for years. At the beginning of Feb we were put on AdBlock's whitelist, per their [Acceptable Ads policy](https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads). That's probably why you just recently started seeing them.